# Why the `std::function` object(i.e `fn`) still works well after the object `ins` is out of scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

Why the `std::function` object(i.e `fn`) still works well after the object `ins` is out of scope?
Here is the code snappit(https://godbolt.org/z/Y6KaWY):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function<int(void)> fn;
 
 class CTest
 {
    public:
         CTest() {std::cout << "ctor:" << this << std::endl;};
         int demo(void){std::cout << "this pointer:" << this << std::endl; return 0;}
 };



 void assign(void)
 {
    CTest ins;
    fn = std::bind(&CTest::demo, &ins); 
 }

int foo()
{
     return 9;
}

 
 int main()
 {
    assign();
    CTest tes1;

    foo();
    fn();
}
```

The outputs:

```
Program returned: 0
Program stdout
ctor:0x7fff64960a80
ctor:0x7fff64960be0
this pointer:0x7fff64960a80  //You see, still point to the object(i.e `ins`) that is out of its scope
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined. A program that has undefined behaviour is allowed to do anything, including, but not limited to, producing reasonable output.

Comment: It's just bad luck that it didn't crash disastrously.

Answer (score 1):

The class `CTest` has no data members and no virtual methods.  When you capture its address (`&ins`) with `std::bind`, you store it inside an instance that is assigned to the global variable `fn`.  When you execute `CTest::demo()` through `fn` you are passing the captured pointer to the method `demo()` as the first parameter (`this`). You are not accessing any members of the class `CTest`. This is all valid. But since you don't know what the user of `fn` will do with the stored pointer, that is going to become invalid at the end of `assign()`, this is classified as undefined behavior.

If you add members to `CTest` and try to access them from `CTest::demo()`, then you will be accessing memory that `this` pointer points to, but that memory is no longer valid and may have been overwritten.

If you add a virtual method and try to execute it from `CTest::demo()` or even if you make `CTest::demo()` virtual, you will most likely call invalid functions, because the pointer to the virtual method table is part of the memory that the captured pointer points to and may have been overwritten.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it doesn't matter if you access members or not, it's still UB.